# First opportunity for document.body.appendChild

Tags: javascript, performance

I am looking for the first opportunity to call `document.body.appendChild` to attach an element. I am currently using `onload` of body but as I understand it this waits until images and subframes load before triggering.

I require only that the solution work in IE (this is for an IE specific demo), but believe in the importance of giving cross-browser answers for other people to reference, so points if you give both.

Below is an illustration of what I am already doing.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Insertion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertStuff() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="insertStuff()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev: OP didn't say it doesn't work.

Comment: @user: Remember to include a doctype, like `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Insertion</title>

      </head>
      <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          function insertStuff() {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
          }
          insertStuff()
          </script>
<!-- Here goes all the other elements -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

This would be cross browser and work for IE6 and above for sure. Not sure about anything below that

Comment: Thank you! Can you add an explanation as to why you chose that method  and what the theory is behind it? If I wasn't appending directly to body, but rather to an element within body (e.g. p in <body><p></p></body>) would I have to put the script within _that_ element (e.g. <p>)?

Comment: ok. What happens here is that when the script tag is read by the document it has the reference to body and would then create an iframe and append it to the body and the code would work just fine. I used it as a function so that whenever I need I can call the same function to add multiple iframes and later the using `window.frames[index]` refer to those iframes as and when required